# script always working in chrome / firefox works only once in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, google-chrome

In a partial view I have these lines of scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#randomCard').click(function () {
            alert("button clicked!");
            $.get("@Url.Action("GetRandomCard")", {}, function (data) {
                $('#rightSide').html(data);
            });
        });
    })
</script>
```

This calls a Get method in my controller which returns a random card from a database. In chrome, this methods is 100% working. Firefox fires the event 100% of the time too. But in IE the action is fired only once while the alert always pops.

Can somebody help me figure out why?

**EDIT**

Following everyone's advice, I have debugged my session which made me realize that the html data was being added, not replaced. I have created an upper div `#rightSide` which gets updated with the data, thus resolving this small problem.

However, the problem of IE calling the partial view controller method is still active and I appreciate everyone's help to resolve this issue.

Comment: `data` is likely not being parsed correctly in IE.

Comment: Well is there another way to render the data, or do the same work?

Comment: you could use $.parseHTML(), but if the html is invalid, it won't fix it.

Comment: I tried and the function makes all the browsers crash...

Comment: you likely used it incorrectly. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML. `$('#cardOfTheDay').html($.parseHTML(data));`

Comment: Well, if it can guide you, using the line you provided did not make the app crash, but not the bug repeats on all browsers. So it's likely that something in the Html(data) is broken, as you suggest. How can I figure it?

Comment: You could start by correctly indenting the html looking for mis-matched tags/quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Fire up a debugger in IE. Run and see what fails.
Catch if there is an error from $.get(…).

( I bet on the randomCard-control being a anchor link and there being i subtle bug that makes the anchor get the page again. )

Don't forget to post your findings.

Comment: Ok, I will try to do so as soon as I find out how to debug in IE.

Comment: @HerveS F12 opens the console.

Comment: @HerveS It is not a bad idea to always have the debugger console open while developing html/javascript. Errors and possibly warnings are outputted there so you can spot them early.

Comment: Ok, from what I'm seeing, the whole page is being added anew, meaning that scripts in it and the whole html body is added instead of being replaced. I did not knew that! Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

even if it is not an

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#randomCard').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("button clicked!");
 //etc
```